If $X \oplus Y$ has a projective cover denoted $P$, can we find projective covers for $X$ and $Y$ respectively?
Let $X, Y$ be two modules over a ring with unity $R$. If $X$ and $Y$ have projective covers denoted $P_X$ and $P_Y$ respectively, then $X \oplus Y$ has a projective cover $P_X \oplus P_Y$. This is easy to prove, and you can see here.
What about the inverse? That is, if $X \oplus Y$ has a projective cover denoted $P$, can we find projective covers for $X$ and $Y$ respectively?

This has previously been asked here, although it didn't get any answers.

Thanks for sharing the information with me.

I've found a counterexample (you might recognize the ring involved!), but since the question I mentioned in my previous comment was asked considerably earlier, I've written it as an answer to that question. Then, when I'm sure that you've seen this, I'll probably vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Thank you for your message and for sharing the counterexample!
